# comparing elements of the same array in java and then deleting the element

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like a[]={1,2,3,4,3,5}, then I want to compare the first element with the 2nd,3rd,4th, and so on... the 2 element with 3,4,3,5..then 3 with 4,3,5...
 
What I am trying to achive here is to delete duplicate elements.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[]= {1,2,1,4,5};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
             if (a[i] == a[k]) {
                 // shifting elements
                 for( k = i; k < a.length-1; k++) {
                     a[k] = a[k+1];
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    for(int l=0;l<a.length;l++)
        System.out.println(a[l]);

}
```

Expected: should remove the duplicate elements at last and my array would have [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: If you dont want use streams for this, not sure why you wouldn't use them, but let's assume you want your approach. You could track the duplicate indices using a Set<Integer> without doing any shifting. Then change the ```if (a[i] == a[k])``` to ```if (!set.contains(k) && a[i] == a[k])``` so you dont check duplicate indices. At the end just make a new array that is the array length minus the set size and copy over every non duplicate index value.

Comment: You can also add a ```continue``` to the first for loop using this approach whenever ```i``` is a duplicate index.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like you want to "de-duplicate" this array.

There are a variety of ways to handle this, but my preferred way would be `Streams` (using `StreamEx`, a wrapper around `Stream` for more verbose code) in Java 8+.

See some other ways here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-duplicates-from-list

So what you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
List<Integer> integersWithDupes = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5);
System.out.println(integersWithDupes.size()); // this is now 6
List<Integer> deduped = StreamEx.of(integersWithDupes).distinct().toList();
System.out.println(deduped.size()); // this is now 5
```

Unless it is a hard requirement for an assignment, I would avoid using arrays and use the `List` interface instead. It wraps a lot of the functionality that you're trying to accomplish in much more expressive and robust ways.

Happy coding!

Comment: There is definitely no need to include a library just for that. You can write `integersWithDupes.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Agreed. The link given has 4 other native ways to achieve the same goal. StreamEx is a common library usually already available via transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for this:

```
int[] a = {1,2,1,4,5};
int[] noDuplicates = IntStream.of(a).distinct().toArray();
```

`IntStream.distinct` will skip all duplicate elements and `toArray()` will then collect the remaining elements in a new array.